# Подскажите с выбором VoIP кодека

Tags: аудио, voip

VoIP кодеков существует достаточно большое количество. Человеку, не сильно разбирающемуся в отличиях между ними, достоинствах и недостатках каждого, выбрать трудновато. Подскажите быстрые современные не лицензированные кодеки (может быть предложите несколько на выбор).

Comment: Тут закроют вопрос, скорее всего, на [**Software Recommendations**](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) попробуйте спросить. Спасибо.

Comment: Для каких целей нужен кодек (конференции, трансляции, звонки между двумя абонентами)? Вопрос очень обобщенный. Можно ли конкретезировать вопрос, например, "Какой кодек широкополосный кодек для аудио можно использовать при видеотрансляции на 50 человек, если скорость входящего канала у клиентов <2 Мбит"?

Comment: Звонки между двумя абонентами

Answer (score 0):

Если не разбираешься и не вникаешь в подробности выбирай то, что по умолчанию в твоей телефонии (наверное это будет G.729 и G.711).

Вы должны сами определиться, что вам надо. Хороший звук или хорошее сжатие для возможности говорить по такому себе 3g ?

Если что, активно по миру шагает opus - почти во всех IM он. Но к сожалению sip еще не подтянулся за нововведениями.

Comment: _Вы должны сами определиться, что вам надо_ - современный нелицензированный кодек, минимально нагружающий процессор и обеспечивающий качественный звук (сжатие если только без потерь).

Comment: flac сжатие без потерь - но такого в телефонии не бывает. Смотри opus - почти все im на нем работают т.к. хорошее качество.

Comment: G.729 требует лицензионных отчислений (не путать с G.729A).

Comment: Но ведь ОПУС - плох, так как принципиально не поддерживает 44 килогерца. Потом пацаны конечно опомнились и запилили... Отдельный кодек под 44 килогерца. И вот теперь есть 2 кодека ОПУС. Одним пользоваться даже не рекомендуют.

Answer (score -1):

Привет, друг! У меня есть идеальный вариант для тебя:

МР3

Преимущества:

- аппаратный декодер практически в каждом чипе, в каждой кофеварке
- высокое качество звука, особенно на 320 килобит
- коммерческое качество как кодировщиков, так и декодировщиков
- большой выбор готовых библиотек под все возможные платформы
- все патенты истекли и его можно спокойно использовать в своих проектах

За годы существования МР3, сообщество написало не мало хороших решений. Тебе остается лишь взять плоды чужих трудов и просто прилинковать их к своему проекту! И никому платить не нужно!

Comment: MP3 же вроде не VoIP кодек...

Comment: А какая разница?